# Cannot call draw function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a project creating layouts and i have decided to do it with canvas element.I created a function that takes 4 args.

```
   function fillArc(camvas,x,y,w,h)
{
canv.beginPath();
    var canv = document.getElementById("camvas");
    var context = canv.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle="#FFFFFF";
    context.moveTo(x+5,y);
    context.lineTo(w-5,y);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(w,y,w,y+5);
    context.lineTo(w,h-5);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(w,h,w-5,h);
    context.lineTo(x+5,h);  
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x,h,x,h-5);
    context.lineTo(x,y+5);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x,y,x+5,y);
    context.stroke();
canv.closePath();


}
```

I have several canvas elements so i want to create this border-radius box in different areas.I assumed that a call like:

```
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvaslayouts">
</canvas>

<script>
fillArc(canvaslayouts,10,10,50,50);
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.Can anyone point my mistake please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/hmpJv/)***

Place your function and the call to it in a `script` element

Pass in a string which matches the `id` of the canvas you wish to draw on

Use the context, not the canvas, to access the drawing API

```
<script>
function fillArc(camvas,x,y,w,h)
{
var canv = document.getElementById(camvas);
var context = canv.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle="#ffffff";
context.moveTo(x+5,y);
context.lineTo(w-5,y);
context.quadraticCurveTo(w,y,w,y+5);
context.lineTo(w,h-5);
context.quadraticCurveTo(w,h,w-5,h);
context.lineTo(x+5,h);  
context.quadraticCurveTo(x,h,x,h-5);
context.lineTo(x,y+5);
context.quadraticCurveTo(x,y,x+5,y);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
}
fillArc("canvaslayouts",10,10,50,50);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in a `<script>` block should do the trick:

```
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvaslayouts"></canvas>
<script>
fillArc(canvaslayouts,10,10,50,50);
</script>
```

Also, note that your `fillArc()` function definition (or any other executable JavaScript that you may have) should also be in a `<script>` block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `.beginPath()` and `.closePath()` calls so that they're applied to the *context*, and not to the *canvas*.

That can of course only be done once you've called `canv.getContext()`.

You also need to:

1. use the correct ID - you've used `"camvas"` when it should be the *variable* with that name
2. put your JS inside `<script>` tags

i.e.:

```
<script>
function fillArc(camvas,x,y,w,h)
{
    var canv = document.getElementById(camvas); 
    var context = canv.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle="#FFFFFF";
    context.moveTo(x+5,y);
    context.lineTo(w-5,y);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(w,y,w,y+5);
    context.lineTo(w,h-5);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(w,h,w-5,h);
    context.lineTo(x+5,h);  
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x,h,x,h-5);
    context.lineTo(x,y+5);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x,y,x+5,y);
    context.closePath();  // NB: close the path before you stroke it
    context.stroke();
}
</script>

<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvaslayouts"> </canvas>
<script>
    fillArc("canvaslayouts", 10, 10, 50, 50);
</script>
```

Comment: I changed the `.beginPath()` and `.closePath()`. I try to call this function in my main .js file or just under the `<canvas>` element but neither of these work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few things:

1. You're never using the `camvas` variable.
2. You're always refering to `#camvas`.
3. You call `canv.beginPath()` before setting `canv` to anything.
4. Your javascript code in the canvas is not in script tags
5. Your javascript code in the canvas tag calls the function with `canvaslayouts` as the first parameter. This means you're searching for a variable named "canvaslayouts" and not an ID. Change it to `"canvaslayouts"` to specify that it's a string to be used in `getElementById`.

The correct code should be something like this:

```
function fillArc(camvas,x,y,w,h)
{
    //Changed to use the variable instead, and moved it to the start
    var canv = document.getElementById(camvas); 
    canv.beginPath();
        var context = canv.getContext('2d');
        context.strokeStyle="#FFFFFF";
        context.moveTo(x+5,y);
        context.lineTo(w-5,y);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(w,y,w,y+5);
        context.lineTo(w,h-5);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(w,h,w-5,h);
        context.lineTo(x+5,h);  
        context.quadraticCurveTo(x,h,x,h-5);
        context.lineTo(x,y+5);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(x,y,x+5,y);
        context.stroke();
    canv.closePath();
}
```

and

```
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvaslayouts">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Use a script container
        fillArc("canvaslayouts",10,10,50,50); //Use a string, not a variable
    </script>
</canvas>
```

Comment: the `beginPath` and `closePath` lines in this code are still incorrect.  In fact the `closePath` isn't even required if your last drawing operation leaves the "cursor" at the point you first started at.

Comment: @Alnitak I was unaware of this. I haven't personally used canvas before, and all I explained was general javascript/DOM manipulation. I appreciate your input, and I hope that if anyone searches for a similar situation and look at this answer, they'll also look at your comment for extra information.